# How to use enum in C?

Tags: c

I have read a lot of documents about enum but I still can't understand the enum clearly.

I have read about the enum syntax, but there are still things that make me wonder:

```
1. How does Enum work? I need more than 1 example of how to use enum? And when should I use it?
2. If I have more than 1 enum, how do I run the loop with each enum.
```

Can someone give me a detailed explanation? Thank you

Comment: Can you share the documents you read about it?

Comment: 1) I guess a quick google will show you a few thousand usecases of enums. "When should I use it?" if you need to represent a state that has more than two possible values (because then a boolean would be appropriate). 2) I don't know what you mean. Could you show an example of what you are trying to do?

Comment: @OriolMiró i'm learning at this web https://www.codesdope.com/c-enum/ 
But they gave me too few examples to understand enum.

Comment: @JonasWilms #include<stdio.h> 
 
enum week{Mon, Tue, Wed, Thur, Fri, Sat, Sun};
 
int main() {
    enum week day;
    day = Wed;
    printf("%d\n", day);
     
    // loop through enum
    int i; 
    for (i = Mon; i <= Sun; i++)
        printf("%d ", i);
    return 0;
}     // So what if i have more than just one enum ?

Comment: In the code shown, there is just one enum?

Comment: @JonasWilms Yes, but I wonder if there is more than one enum, how can we know which enum is running in the loop?

Comment: As pointed out in the answer below "enums are just numbers", and you basically iterate over numbers. So when iterating the number is not coupled in any way to the enum. However, if you look at your example above, you iterate from `i = Mon` to `i <= Sun` so it is clear that i represents a weekday (i is a bad name, just saying).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enums simply provide a type with keywords that translate into numbers at compile time. It is not possible to iterate over them as C does not have much in the way of introspective capability, and they are simply placeholders for numerical values (by default counting up from 0). Example:

```
enum test {
  FIRST,
  SECOND,
  THIRD
};
```

You can also manually specify the numbers they translate to:

```
enum test {
  FIRST=1,
  SECOND=2,
  THIRD=3
};
```

This is particularly useful when you want a datatype to have different states or properties but using a plain numerical value would be unclear. This means that rather than doing something like:

```
if (status == 2)
```

which means the programmer has to figure out what `2` means you can do:

```
if (status == READ)
```

Which is much clearer.